# kiln v0.5.2 LevelWarn internalnode LOCK HELD error

Tags: kiln

Is there a way to fix this error?

May 27 17:32:25 mi run-kiln[5527]: 27-May-2019 17:32:24LevelWarn""internalnode LOCK HELD
May 27 17:32:27 mi run-kiln[5527]: 27-May-2019 17:32:27LevelWarn""internalnode LOCK HELD
May 27 17:32:30 mi run-kiln[5527]: 27-May-2019 17:32:30LevelWarn""internalnode LOCK HELD
May 27 17:32:33 mi run-kiln[5527]: 27-May-2019 17:32:33LevelWarn""internalnode LOCK HELD
May 27 17:32:35 mi run-kiln[5527]: 27-May-2019 17:32:35LevelWarn""("blockWorker","block cannot be retrieved from available nodes","BLfkNYmz6AocSbPBkuG9SawiY9b9PTpNZ6DFzFJseEU3gTqhQZM")

Answer (score 1):

You should find that this resolves itself after 5 minutes. This is a known bug in kiln.